# Not able to manage JBoss through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jboss

When I execute my specific startJBoss.sh file through Jenkins, it starts JBoss but the server does not send any feedback saying "start successful". And because of that I am not able to start another processes. What s the solution for that.

The job is always running, If I cancel the job, JBoss stops.

Solution Please

Regards
Manish Mehra

Answer (score 0):

I have a nightly build that I do that rebuilds and tests my environment from end to end.  I do the jboss startup and shut down from a bat file and just put a pause after the start (using the ping kluge) to give jboss enough time to start.  Probably not the best solution but I've been running this for over a year now with out a single issue.